# How do you cast a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I made an array of blocks. I want to execute an individual block from the array and I am having trouble finding what the syntax is to cast and call the block.

```
 void (^hiBlock)() = ^void() {
        NSLog(@"Hi");
    };

    void (^byeBlock)() = ^void() {
        NSLog(@"Bye");
    };

    NSArray *blocks = @[hiBlock, byeBlock];
    (void (^)(void))blocks[0]();
```

Comment: You missed brackets - `((void (^)(void))blocks[0])();`

Comment: !!!That was easy thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `typedef` to make your life easier.  The following works:

```
typedef void (^HiBlockType)();

HiBlockType hiBlock = ^{ NSLog(@"Hi"); };
HiBlockType byeBlock = ^{ NSLog(@"Bye"); };

NSArray *blocks = @[ hiBlock, byeBlock ];
((HiBlockType)blocks[0])();
```

Also note that this is essentially `dispatch_block_t`, so you could just use that instead of `HiBlockType`.